# if condition inside a for-each loop in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a xml of the below mentioned format:

```
<Root>
<Book name="Type" value="Action" />
<Book name="Price" value="10" />
<Book name="color" value="yellow" />
</Root>
```

What i want is, i have to iterate through this loop and if "Price" exists , then i have to assign "10" to another variable. What i tried to do is :

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Root/Book">
<xsl:if test="./@name = 'Price'">
<sample name="{@name}" value="{@value}" />
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But i am getting a could not compile style sheet exception

Comment: When I run this through xsltproc, it works.  Could you show the exception you're getting?

Comment: @legoscia, thank you !actually there was a typos in the question i posted, i intened to post <xsl:if test="./@name = "'Price'" ">, but i think the typo is the solution to my problem !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't xsl:for-each select="" working with this xml file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870687/why-isnt-xslfor-each-select-working-with-this-xml-file)