# Why isn't xsl:for-each select="" working with this xml file?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, foreach

I am trying to display an xml file with an xsl stylesheet. I just canNOT seem to get it to work.

The feed I'm using is this: http://screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com/atom.xml

Here is an abbreviated copy of the xml for it:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:ts="http://www.travelscream.com">
    <title type="text">Travelscream Deal Alerts</title>
    <updated>2012-08-08T11:09:44-06:00</updated>
    <id>http://screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com/</id>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" hreflang="en" href="http://screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com"/>
    <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com/atom.xml"/>
    <generator uri="http://screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com" version="1.0">screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com</generator>
    <entry>
        <title>New York City: Best Western President Hotel - $152</title>
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com/a477908344.htm"/>
        <id>http://screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com/a477908344.htm</id>
        <updated>2012-08-08T11:09:44-06:00</updated>
        <published>2012-08-08T00:00:00-06:00</published>
        <author>
            <name>screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com</name>
            <uri>http://screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com</uri>
        </author>
        <content type="html" xml:base="screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com" xml:lang="en"> &lt;table&gt; &lt;tr&gt; &lt;td valign="middle"&gt; &lt;img width="80" width="60"
            src="http://www.dealbase.com/assets/hotels/photos/000/002/953/icon.jpg"&gt; &lt;/td&gt; &lt;td valign="top"&gt; $152/night &amp; up - Best Western President Hotel (New York City, NY) - 46%
            Off Travel Dates: Through Dec 31, 2012 &lt;/td&gt; &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;/table&gt; </content>
        <ts:data>
            <ts:primarykey>477908344</ts:primarykey>
            <ts:location_data>
                <ts:location id="50" selected="0" airport_codes="EWR,JFK,LGA" type="dest">New York</ts:location>
                <ts:location id="55" selected="1" airport_codes="EWR,JFK,LGA" type="dest">New York City</ts:location>
                <ts:location id="199" selected="0" airport_codes="" type="dest">United States</ts:location>
                <ts:location id="288" selected="0" airport_codes="" type="dest">North America</ts:location>
                <ts:location id="524" selected="0" airport_codes="EWR,JFK,LGA,NYC" type="dest">Manhattan</ts:location>
                <ts:location id="525" selected="0" airport_codes="EWR,JFK,LGA,NYC" type="dest">Bronx</ts:location>
                <ts:location id="526" selected="0" airport_codes="EWR,JFK,LGA,NYC" type="dest">Brooklyn</ts:location>
                <ts:location id="527" selected="0" airport_codes="EWR,JFK,LGA" type="dest">Queens</ts:location>
                <ts:location id="528" selected="0" airport_codes="EWR,JFK,LGA" type="dest">Staten Island</ts:location>
                <ts:location id="613" selected="0" airport_codes="" type="dest">SoHo</ts:location>
            </ts:location_data>
            <ts:pkg_attributes>
                <ts:attribute id="3" type="TYPE">Honeymoon</ts:attribute>
                <ts:attribute id="40" type="MAIN">Hotel</ts:attribute>
                <ts:attribute id="62" type="DTYP">City</ts:attribute>
            </ts:pkg_attributes>
            <ts:deal_expires>2012-09-07T14:54:05-06:00</ts:deal_expires>
            <ts:deal_supplier>DealBase.com</ts:deal_supplier>
            <ts:feed_image>http://www.dealbase.com/assets/hotels/photos/000/002/953/icon.jpg</ts:feed_image>
            <ts:fullscreen_image/>
            <ts:price1>15200</ts:price1>
            <ts:alpha>0</ts:alpha>
            <ts:coord>
                <ts:lat>40.7606</ts:lat>
                <ts:long>-73.9864</ts:long>
                <ts:latlong>40.7606,-73.9864</ts:latlong>
            </ts:coord>
            <ts:desc>$152/night &amp; up - Best Western President Hotel (New York City, NY) - 46% Off Travel Dates: Through Dec 31, 2012</ts:desc>
            <ts:tacomm/>
            <ts:direct>true</ts:direct>
            <ts:top>false</ts:top>
            <ts:traveldates>
                <ts:from>01/01/2050</ts:from>
                <ts:to>01/01/2050</ts:to>
            </ts:traveldates>
        </ts:data>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

the php page that loads up the stylesheet and tells it to transform the xml is coded thusly:

```
$xp = new XsltProcessor();
// create a DOM document and load the XSL stylesheet
$xsl = new DomDocument;
$xsl->load('deals_stylesheet.xsl');

// import the XSL styelsheet into the XSLT process
$xp->importStylesheet($xsl);

// create a DOM document and load the XML datat
$xml_doc = new DomDocument;
$xml_doc->load('http://screamingdeals.tdn.travelscream.com/atom.xml');

// transform the XML into HTML using the XSL file
if ($html = $xp->transformToXML($xml_doc)) {
    echo $html;
} else {
    trigger_error('XSL transformation failed.', E_USER_ERROR);
} // if
```

So far...so good. I'm not getting an error.
Here is the xsl file contents:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
                <title>Facebook Deals Page</title>
                <style type="text/css">
                    <![CDATA[
                        <!--

                        -->
                    ]]>
                </style>
            </head>

            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Title</b></td>
                        <td><b>ID</b></td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="feed/entry">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="id"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is a display of it not working: http://www.margaretpickarddesign.com/clients/travelscream/facebook_deals/facebook_rss.php

Looking at the xml structure, the node "feed" is followed by node "entry" which has child nodes "title" and "id". So why isn't it working? What am I missing?

Comment: Please show the input XML. The link to the atom feed is not sufficient, as the data will change.  Please show a specific XML that is not working.

Comment: I didn't look at the feed, but I'm 99% sure it's a namespace issue. Search SO for "xslt default namespace" and you should have enough info to figure out the problem.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I added the xml.

Comment: @DevNull - I am very confused by the namespace in this file. It's some ts: thing that doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. So you could be right but searching for information on this has not gotten me anywhere. Would you be so good as to take a look and tell me what your thoughts are about what namespace I should define as the default and/or how to handle the "ts" namespace? Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSLT template match doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792360/xslt-template-match-doesnt-work)

Comment: The `ts` prefixed namespace isn't the problem because you're not accessing any elements in that namespace. The problem is the default namespace (the xmlns with no prefix). What you need to do is add `xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` to `xsl:stylesheet` and use that prefix in your selects. (`select="a:feed/a:entry"`, `select="a:title"`, and `select="a:id"`) Also note that you can use any prefix, not just "a". The only thing that has to be the same is the namespace itself (`http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`).

Comment: @DevNull, any particular reason why you wrote this as a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @DevNull you are right and your "comment" is the correct answer. It works! I need to go spend more time understanding xml namespaces. I can't seem to wrap my brains around them. THANK YOU from the bottom of my heart!

Comment: For future reference, I found this article on XML namespaces and it helped a LOT. A little antiquated but very easy to understand. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468565.aspx.

Comment: @MvG - You're right, that comment should've been an answer. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding comment as an actual answer...

The `ts` prefixed namespace isn't the problem because you're not accessing any elements in that namespace. The problem is the default namespace (the xmlns with no prefix).

What you need to do is add `xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"` to `xsl:stylesheet` and use that prefix in your selects. (`select="a:feed/a:entry"`, `select="a:title"`, and `select="a:id"`)

Also note that you can use any prefix, not just "a". The only thing that has to be the same is the namespace itself (`http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`).